# Refactoring code duplication inside function

Tags: python, nuke

I want to refactor the `assign_hotkey` function, because I do not like the duplicated code in the if-statement.

**The code:**

```
n_path_i = 0
c_node_i = 1
h_key_i = 2

hotkeys = [
        ['Filter/Blur', 'Blur, size 20 label "hello world"', 'A'],
        ['Draw/LightWrap', 'LightWrap', 'B'],
        ['Draw/Grain', 'Grain2', 'X']
        ]

def assign_hotkey(n_path, c_node, h_key):
    c_node_splitted = c_node.split(',')
    if len(c_node_splitted) > 1:
        menu.addCommand(n_path, 
                        lambda: nuke.createNode(*c_node_splitted),
                        h_key)
    else:
        menu.addCommand(n_path, 
                        lambda: nuke.createNode(c_node),
                        h_key)

for i in hotkeys:
    assign_hotkey(i[n_path_i], i[c_node_i], i[h_key_i])
```

Comment: This belongs at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: uhh, sorry, I did not know about this, thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This belongs at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Before posting on Code Review, make sure you've read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so you know what's expected of a question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are unpacking the list you get from splitting `c_node` when you pass it to `nuke.createNode`, there is no reason to make a special case at all for the length of the list being 1.

You can change:

```
if len(c_node_splitted) > 1:
    menu.addCommand(n_path, 
                    lambda: nuke.createNode(*c_node_splitted),
                    h_key)
else:
    menu.addCommand(n_path, 
                    lambda: nuke.createNode(c_node),
                    h_key)
```

to:

```
menu.addCommand(n_path, 
                lambda: nuke.createNode(*c_node_splitted),
                h_key)
```